# Getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query even through JNDI

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jndi, connection-pooling

I use Struts2+JSP+Tomcat6+Hibernate+Mysql as my J2EE application framework.Following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218663/keep-getting-org-hibernate-exception-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-execute-q) topic, I've had the problem of getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
```

It appears to be due to the fact that mysql closes it's connections after n hours.
As people answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218663/keep-getting-org-hibernate-exception-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-execute-q) I changed the hibernate config to get my db connections through JNDI.here is the course of actions which I've taken to do this:

my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/hposg</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>

      <!-- Mapping files -->

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the context.xml file that I've put in META-INF derictory:

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/hposg" 
            global="jdbc/hposg"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            username="root"
            password=""
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hposg?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            maxActive="8" 
            maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

and these modifications in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/hposg</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Strangely enough I still get the same error! here is the stacktrace:

```
'org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2297)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:859)
    at com.hposg.domain.HPOSG.getPlayerByID(HPOSG.java:117)
    at com.hposg.login.UserSession.getPlayerById(UserSession.java:39)
    at com.hposg.controller.struts.PortfolioLoadAction.execute(PortfolioLoadAction.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1032.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor109.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2720)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2436)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2703)
    ... 85 more
'
```

[EDIT]
I made a few changes to the context.xml and the problem seems to be solved:

```
maxActive="-1" 
maxIdle="30"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
testWhileIdle="true"
```

[EDIT_2]
Despite the modifications I mentioned before, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue in a production system with Tomcat6+Hibernate+MySQL (and Spring in our case) and the only reliable solution we found was to set the connection timeout to a large value in the MySQL configuration. I cannot remember the particulars but I believe there was an issue with the underlying [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) code when it verifies that pooled resource is valid.

Another possibility that we did not try was to use an alternate Connection Pooling mechanism other than DBCP. Next to try would be [C3PO](http://java-source.net/open-source/connection-pools/c3p0)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `tcpKeepAlive=true` to the JDBC URL.

Comment: Thanks Brent, as I mentioned above in [EDIT] section, I made a few changes and it seems to solve the issue. Otherwise I'll take your idea into consideration.

Comment: I did this and unfortunately the situation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is
`url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hposg?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"`.
But `autoReconnect` is not recommended ([here](http://pages.citebite.com/p4x3a0r8pmhm)). Instead, try increasing the timeout by adding this to my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=864000
wait_timeout=864000
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and got no proper solution.
after that i follow below link for c3p0 and i got my solution.
This link is very helpful for above problem

http://syntx.io/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/