# sometime i lose my database connection using hibernate , what could be the reason?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

i have made a application using Struts2 and Hibernate. 
But now i am facing a  problem. 
  For the first time browsing my project pages, all the data will be displaying correctly from my db. But if i continue browsing my pages, then after few mins/hour i am unable to see the database table data into my html page. (My DAO class unable to give the table values and throws error like 
`Exception in  getSubjects()  :org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query`)
Or even if i do not touch my application( i.e idle ), and after few mins if i come and browse my data then also i am getting the same error 
`Exception in  getSubjects()  :org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query`.

And i receive a blank data in the subject column and slowly in next click i loses all the data and hibernate throws the same error for all the the list.

**Problem:** *SOMETIME MY DAO IS RETURNING THE LIST AND SOMETIME IT IS NOT RETURNING THE LIST*

What could be the reason for this? Please help me to solve this issue. I made this application by spending so much of my time.

A method from My SubjectdetailsDAO.java (method where i am getting above mentioned error )

```
   `   public List getSubjects(String subjectname)
        {
      List list=null;
        try{ 
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            list=session.createCriteria(Subjectdetails.class).add(Expression.like("subjectName", "%" + subjectname + "%")).list();
         }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in  getSubjects()  :" + e);
            } finally {
                try {
                     session.flush();
                    session.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception In getSubjects Resource closing  :" + e);
                }
            } 
            return list; 
        } `
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
             `      package v.esoft.connection; import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

    public class HibernateUtil {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

            }
            catch (Throwable ex) 
            {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it  might be swallowed
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static void shutdown() {
            // Close caches and connection pools
            getSessionFactory().close();
        } 
    }`
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   `        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory name="vbsofwaresession">
            <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ashutosh</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vbsoftware</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ashutosh</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Themes" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Usertype" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Login" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Coverdetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Editiondetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Bookdetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Soldbookdetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Languagedetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Locationdetails" />
            <mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Subjectdetails" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

`

Comment: Show your database connection configuration.

Comment: way too much code, give us the minimum possible to reproduce.

Comment: @AleksandrM I updated hibernate.cfg.xml. Please see it above

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5340316/422353) deals with a similar (the same?) problem.

Comment: I'll second "too much code".  It doesn't look like you're consistent about closing sessions.

Comment: @duffymo  why i posted that code because you can see my one sample DAO class. Like i am properly using hibernate Session or Not? Thats you i  kept it.

Comment: yes you seem to be not closing sessions in some methods

Comment: show us your complete stack trace, it will show us the exact cause of the problem. The exception message you gave was a generic one.

Comment: @SajanChandran What is stack trace? I am only seeing console in my eclipse where that error is generated

Comment: Mysql has a habit of "going away", but it comes back if you retry. Consider retrying if the operation fails.

Comment: Consider using connection pool.

Comment: @Bohemian yes if i refresh the page then again the lost values comes . But this is not the solution .

Comment: The best approach is to use a connection pool, which will test the connection before giving it to you to use, refreshing it if necessary. Have a look at C3P0 or the Apache impl