# Getting "could not execute query" error after 13hrs of inactivity

Tags: hibernate, openjpa

I have following setup:
JSP/Servlet => Presentation layer.
Hibernate and OpenJPA => Data access layer.

To connect to the database I am adding the configuration information in a "persistence.xml" file. Here are the entries for the "persistence.xml" file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/test?autoReconnect=true"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxx"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxx"/>
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1800"/>
<property name="c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="1810"/>
```

I am getting `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query` error. After 13 or more hours of inactivity. This error is not consistently reproduced. I am not able to reproduce the error on my test setup but this error is coming on the production server.

I have searched the forum there are some entry which is similar to mine but they do not answer my question. The links are:

[Getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query even through JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340316/getting-org-hibernate-exception-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-execute-query)

[Keep getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218663/keep-getting-org-hibernate-exception-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-execute)

Am I missing some setting or doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you have OpenJPA tagged for this question?

Comment: What is the query that you are executing? How much data is being returned by the query when running in production?

Comment: `@Rick` I am getting this error while logging into the application. The query I am executing is `SELECT * from user WHERE userid=x AND password=xxx` This query is returning only a single record.

Comment: Does this happen with OpenJPA, or just Hibernate? Are you able to execute any other queries?

Comment: As this is the first query to log-in to the system I had not checked if any other query gets executed or not. But when I retry to login it succeed as there is `?autoReconnect=true` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was c3p0 version issue. On using the latest c3p0 version the issue was not observed. Also some connections leak use to happen when exception was thrown. Add the connection releasing code in the finally block worked.